# HBase complex Filter not returning all columns

Tags: hbase

```
val scan = new Scan()
val hBaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val hUsers = new HTable(hBaseConf, "users")
val filterOnA = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Constants.CF_META, Bytes.toBytes("id"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUALS, Bytes.toBytes("##"))
val filterOnB = new FamilyFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("some_value")))
val filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL)
filterList.addFilter(filterOnA)
filterList.addFilter(filterOnB)
hUsers.getScanner(scan.setFilter(filterList))
```

The code above has some strange results. The HBase scanner DOES return correctly filtered Results (passing both Filters in the list), however the column of filterOnA is NOT passed back by the server in the Results. Only the KV's of the CF of filterOnB are there.

I have tried a number of things like `scan.addFamily(Constants.CF_META)` but that causes the scanner to be empty. Shouldn't the scanner return ALL columns by default for all KV's satisfying both filters?

I wonder if the compound filter logic is 'smart' enough to handle 2 filters applied at 2 distinct CF's at seperate locations/regionservers.

Answer (score 0):

`SingleColumnValueFilter` filter rows by the given value of a column, but *then* you apply a `FamilyFilter`, so I would expect just the KV of this CF to be returned. The first filter does not filter the columns you want, but it is a restriction on whether the row is considered or not (passes that filter or not). Then the family filter select just he `"some_value"` CF, but not the other.